# Social Security in France and access to medical services for cross border worker with Germany

Tags: germany, france, social-security, german-citizens

I am living in Germany and work in France and have to cross the border each day. It’s been like this for a while and I’ve never had problems. But I have received notifications from my doctors that I no longer can use medical and dental services in Germany as I am currently not insured. I do have my French SS number as well as German and not sure what happened. Can anyone give me an idea where to start? I have already had two canceled appointments. After that I called my insurance company in Germany.

First person that I spoke to told me that the Plus Server company removed my insurance in 2016.

After talking to a second person who is responsible for people that work cross the border, they told me that I had insurance until the end of last year. They said the French insurance sent information that I only was limited time working in France till end of last year (2021).

Then I asked my German insurance what they need and they told me the S1 document or the digital version of it called the S072.
Does that mean I have at the moment no insurance, not in Germany and not in France?

Can someone suggest the correct direction to find out what is actually happening?

Comment: You are, what one calls, a **Grenzgänger**. There are many organisations that help out for many complicated situations that can occur. This site lists some of them: [Beratung und Vermittlung — Großregion](https://www.grossregion.net/Buerger/Arbeiten/Beratung-und-Vermittlung) (in German). I would suggest selecting one and ask them for assistance to sort this out.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The English-language terminology is “cross-border worker“ as the OP apparently knows already (French: *travailleur frontalier*).

Comment: EU law says you are entitled to health insurance coverage in the country where you live (i.e. Germany). Not sure about the practicalities in Germany.

Comment: is [this reference](https://britishingermany.org/2020/12/04/residency-in-germany-after-transition/) of any help?